# Delete data after you paste from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, count, reference, row

I am trying to copy data from one spreadsheet and paste it another spreadsheet. Whatever data below my recent paste I want to delete. Issue is that I might not always have an empty cell below my paste since I'm pasting over old data so sometimes I will overwrite over old data but sometimes I won't.

I've tried counting the rows that I'm copying and then using that reference cell/value in the other spreadsheet to delete after but I don't always get the correct row to begin deleting.

```
Dim lr As Long

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (lr)

Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet3").Select
Range("A2").Select
'Selection.End(xlDown).Select
'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("A" & (lr + 1)).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: How about you delete before you paste?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub CopyDataToSheet3()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    'Get the last row with data in Sheet3
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Check if the last row with data is after row 1
    If lastRow > 1 Then
        'Clear contents of rows 2 to lastRow
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End If

    'Copy data from Sheet2 to Sheet3
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2")
End Sub
```